# How to make $.get() function synchronous in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make $.get() method synchronous in my function. In ajax `aysnc : false` helps me, now how do i do the same to to `$.get()`

```
var ifsc_code = $('#ifsc-code').val();
var api_url = 'http://api.techm.co.in/api/v1/ifsc/'+ifsc_code;
$.get(api_url, function(data, status){
//console.log(data.status);

var status = data.status;


  if (data.status == "success") {

      $.each(data,function(key,value){
       var address = value.BANK+", " + value.BRANCH+", " + value.ADDRESS ;
        $('.bank-details').removeClass('no-ifsc').text(address);
        });
        var res = "true";
        alert('inside checkIfsc true');
        return res;
        }

        else if (data.status == "failure") {
         $('.bank-details').addClass('no-ifsc').text(data.message);
         var res = "false";
         alert('inside checkIfsc false');
         return res;
        }
```

Or is there any other approach to do the same ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's almost always a very bad idea. If the server is slow to respond, it will lock up the browser. And in some browsers, it will lock up *every* browser window and tab. If the purpose is to make your code easier to write, you should bite the bullet and write proper asynchronous code that avoids these problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) also accepts parameter like this

```
$.get({
  url: url,// mandatory
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false // to make it synchronous
});
```

Comment: Good to know is that this will make your browser/page freeze until request has finished

Comment: interesting! didn't know that (FYI: just a caveat that Chrome gives a warning that asynchronous XMLHTTPRequest is deprecated)

Comment: This would have been exactly the behavior I need but on Chrome headless it seems to not  retrieve any content.

Answer (score 5):

Although already answered:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  async: false
});
```

I want to warn of you the following:

- Blocks javascript execution, and might thus lock the webpage (no buttons working etc etc, it looks like your page hangs during the ajax call)
- Using synchronous calls gives console warnings.

Javascript is build based on event-driven design. you could also fire an custom named event (with the data result in the event data) when the ajax/get call is  complete and let the followup action listen to this event.

eg:

```
$(form).on('submit',function(){
   var formEl = this;
   $.get({...}).success(function(data){
     var event = new Event('data-submitted');
     event.data = data; 
     formEl.dispatchEvent(event);
   })
});
$(form).on('data-submitted',function(event){
  var data = event.data;
  // you can handle the post ajax request event here.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

add an object parameter

```
$.get({
url: 'your-url',
async:false
});
```